# Compare responses in SoapUI in order to assert case insensitivity

Tags: case, soapui, case-sensitive, assertion

we have a web service that is supposed to be case insenisitive. So, we want the same result on a search for 'foo' and 'FOO'. What is the best way to create an assertion that compares the response for the two different string parameters?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not compare the two results at all.  Your tests could just test the response you receive.  So if you are testing each response the same you would be verifying the responses match.

If using soapUI open source, I would create two tests that are exactly the same except for the data, probably use a [test case property](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/working-with-properties.html).  My requests and response assertions would be the same, but the data is extracted.

If I'm using soapUI Pro, I could have one test case that uses a data sheet, which is alot easier to maintain going forward, but that costs money.

If you want to know what exactly to assert in your test, you will need to look at your requirements and decide which pieces are important to assert.  If the answer is the whole request a simple xpath match against the entire soap envelope would work.

If you must, groovy is the answer,  I think something like this should work:

```
def rawRequest = context.expand( '${Teststepname#RawRequest#declare namespace soapenv=\'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\'; //soapenv:Body[1]}' )
def rawRequest2 = context.expand( '${Teststepname2#RawRequest#declare namespace soapenv=\'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\'; //soapenv:Body[1]}' )

if (rawRequest == rawRequest2) {
    assert true
    }
    else {
        assert false
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see your point. But since I want to test case insensitivity I have to compare the full results but the database data could change without my knowledge. So I don't want to hard code the results.